# How to make multiple GridViews from a List of DataTables, size is unknown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get multiple GridView from a list of DataTables. So far the code below is working. I make the List and for each over each result and pass it to my Panel.

I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do something like this? So far styling has been confusing and would rather style individual rows.

```
private void DisplayData()
{
    DataTable dt = DataAccess.GetData();
    List<DataTable> results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ID"))
                    .Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
                    .ToList();
    foreach (DataTable result in results)
    {
        GridView gv = new GridView();

        gv.Attributes.Add("class", "table pull-left");
        gv.Attributes.Add("style", "table-layout: fixed");
        gv.DataSource = result;
        gv.DataBind();
        pnlResult.Controls.Add(gv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to use the CssClass property of the GridView and then in CSS you can style the class itself. Does this answer your question?